# How to efficiently create a table of nrow over a series of data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, stack, lapply

**UPDATE** Using different solutions found throughout the site:

I still *cannot* achieve the **desired output** using the stack and ldply functions:

**The desired output would look like this:**

```
  Dataset              Samples
1     WGS        nrow(WGS.ped)
2     WES    nrow(WES.ped.exp)
3    MIPS   nrow(MIPS.ped.exp)
```

1) `ldply`: How to assign a name to columns `V1` and `.id`?

```
ldply(list(WGS=WGS.ped, WES=WES.ped.exp, MIPS=mips.ped.exp), 
      function(l)(Samples=nrow(l)))

   .id    V1
1  WGS  3908
2  WES 26367
3 MIPS 14193
```

2) `ldply`: How to assign a name to columns `V1` and `.id`?

```
ldply(list(WGS=WGS.ped, WES=WES.ped.exp, MIPS=mips.ped.exp), nrow)

   .id    V1
1  WGS  3908
2  WES 26367
3 MIPS 14193
```

3) `lapply %>% as.data.frame` : Returns the data frame names as columns, instead of as a first column '`Dataset`'.

```
lapply(list(WGS=WGS.ped, WES=WES.ped.exp, MIPS=mips.ped.exp), nrow) %>% 
  as.data.frame

   WGS   WES  MIPS
1 3908 26367 14193
```

4) `sapply %>% stack` : How to reverse the order of the columns? And how to indicate column names with `stack`?

```
sapply(list(WGS=WGS.ped, WES=WES.ped.exp, MIPS=mips.ped.exp), nrow) %>% 
  stack()

  values  ind
1   3908  WGS
2  26367  WES
3  14193 MIPS
```

5) `map %>% as.data.frame` : Returns the data frame names as columns, instead of as a first column '`Dataset`'.

```
map(list(WGS=WGS.ped, WES=WES.ped.exp, MIPS=mips.ped.exp), nrow) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

 WGS   WES  MIPS 
 3908 26367 14193
```

---

I have three data frames `WGS.ped, WES.ped,exp` and `MIPS.ped.exp`.

I want to create a new data frame that summarizes their row count / the total number of rows in each data frame.

**The desired output would look like this:**

```
Dataset Samples
WGS     nrow(WGS.ped)
WES     nrow(WES.ped.exp)
MIPS    nrow(MIPS.ped.exp)
```

What is an efficient and reproducible way to achieve this, preferably with dplyr?

Thanks!

Comment: `sapply(list(df1, df, 2, df3), nrow)`?

Comment: If you actually have many a data.frame, then check out my answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames).

Comment: The `sapply` solution *almost* works with `stack`, but I can't quite format it to the desired output. I just updated with an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, *this* was especially fun to figure out. Here's a revised solution that only requires `dplyr`. It takes advantage of the base function `mget`, which builds us a *named* list of our dataframes by grabbing them from our R environment after we pass it a vector of names to look for.

Following that, it's just a matter of using `.id` in `bind_rows()` to create a "dummy" column of the dataframe names, which lets us neatly group and summarise.

```
library(dplyr)

# Load some built-in dataframes to use as an example
df1 <- mtcars
df2 <- iris
df3 <- PlantGrowth

names_list <- c("df1","df2","df3")
summary_df <- mget(names_list, envir = globalenv()) %>%
              bind_rows(.id = "Dataset") %>%
              group_by(Dataset) %>%
              summarise(Samples = n())

# Output
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Dataset Samples
  <chr>     <int>
1 df1          32
2 df2         150
3 df3          30
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about, `map` ; but how is it different to `lapply`? 
I wish there was a way to more efficiently create the final table after `map` / `lapply` . i.e., without having to manually specify the names column and the values column.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"? Do you mean using less code? Or do you mean using less computer resources?  Personally, I think it's usually a good idea to use the method which is the most *readable*.

Comment: I agree, but I'd like to avoid the manual specification of the columns for the final table. Later in the script I'd like to replicate the table using a new set of data frames.

Comment: Hmm okay. That's an interesting request. Let me think about it for a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the update! 

I'm following you up until `group_by(Dataset)` -- After running `summarise(nrows = n())`, I get: `Error: This function should not be called directly`. 

Where are you specifying the name of the summary column as `Samples`?

Comment: Never mind, looks like it's a conflict in my session with plyr's `summarise`.  Trying it out again...

Comment: This is such an elegant solution!  
FYI, I tried it without specifying the environment to `mget`and it works as well.

Comment: I learned some new things in the process of getting it to this point, so thank you for pushing me to give you a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base r function that will summarize data frames you pass to it:

```
summarize_data <- function(...) {

  data <- list(...)

  call <- as.character(match.call())

  names <- gsub(".*\\((.*)\\).*", "\\1", call)[-1]


  data.frame(names = names,
             rows = sapply(data, nrow),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

}
```

This gets:

```
> summarize_data(mtcars, iris)


   names rows
1 mtcars   32
2   iris  150
```